# Avatars in chat keep flashing black?

Tags: bug, chat, gravatar, profile-picture

I'm getting weird visual issues with the chat avatars that I didn't used to.  Some of them will now 'flash black' roughly once every 10 seconds, eg. the third from left here:

[image]
[image]

In addition, for some icons when I hover over them, they become "not washed out" (correct), but when I unhover them, they 'flash black' like this briefly before going back to being washed out.

This happens both in my default profile, and also if I create a brand new profile.

I've tried clearing cache and reloading with ctrl+shift+r, but it doesn't fix it.  My browser is Firefox 11, operating system Windows XP SP2.

Comment: It's perhaps not quite flashing "black" - it's more like flashing "dark".

Comment: Come on everyone isn't this worthy of some investigation?  I'm pretty sure it's a genuine bug!

Comment: Hm. +1 because I used to get that, but it doesn't happen now. I just assumed it was fixed.